# Why does downvote sometimes seem to mean 'no'?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Many times on Meta, but not necessarily non-Meta sites, I see yes/no questions. And questions where the answer is no are very often downvoted. Why is that? Why does downvote mean 'no'? I thought downvote meant 'I disagree' or 'low quality question'.

Comment: In most cases, "no" and "I disagree" are synonymous.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog That would be the case for feature requests but not for *question* questions.

Comment: The most common reason I've seen [tag:discussion] and [tag:support] questions get downvoted is because they didn't do enough research on how the system currently works.

Comment: Are you asking about Meta or main sites? If main, then you're probably describing something that doesn't happen on every site or even in all types of questions on a single site. Please provide examples, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Do you have an example question where downvotes meant "no" but not "I disagree"? I don't think I've seen any.

Answer (score 9):

Generally 'Yes/No' questions are not a great fit for the question and answer format. Downvotes on main sites *shouldn't* be for disagreement. They should entirely be a reflection on quality.

Meta's a bit more complicated. In a sense it acts as our system of governance - and to an extent, downvotes as disagreement allows for gauging sentiment on a topic, especially on per site metas. On per site metas the lack of a reputation system of their own means there's no real consequence to the user from it.

MSE works like a 'regular' site mechanically but culturally is a meta site.

Unfortunately downvotes here *can* be a reflection of a user feeling a post is poor quality *or* of disagreement.

That said if you're disagreeing, its also worth answering, commenting or upvoting a relevant existing answer too in order to let folks know what you think.