# Why was my question - Why does downvoting mean 'no?' - downvoted?

Tags: support, down-votes, meta, specific-question

I asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388266)  which ended up with a -7 score.

However, I am puzzled. It seems to be a legitimate question. While I understand that feature requests are downvoted to indicate disagreement, I do not see why many questions whose answer happens to be 'no' get downvoted. As such, I asked about this and got downvoted. I see this as a legitimate question.

I'm not upset or anything. This is a dummy account anyway and I don't really care about the reputation. I am just confused by the number of seemingly legitimate Meta questions that are nevertheless heavily downvoted, including mine.

So yes, *[How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying)* is a useful post and I can relate to that, but here I am asking specifically about my question.

Comment: Ah-ha, there's a fairly comprehensive post about that here: [How do I participate on meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying).

Comment: Just FYI, asking this type of question [hasn't worked for me before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341379/377214).

Comment: Why/how doesn't Journeyman's answer to that question also answer this question? [Why does downvote sometimes seem to mean 'no'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388266/why-does-downvote-sometimes-seem-to-mean-no)

Comment: Votes on meta sites also includes/indicates agreement/disagreement. This is sadly not clearly communicated by SO/SE Inc.

Comment: In a nutshell, on meta sites, being legitimate doesn't mean it won't get downvotes. Totally legit question can get -1000, if 1000 users will disagree with the question and/or idea behind it.

Answer (score 6):

The premise of that question is wrong.

> I thought downvote meant 'I disagree' or 'low quality question'.

No, that is not at all what a down vote means. The tooltip clearly says:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

If this had been 2008 then there wouldn't be much guidance to research but today the downvotes have been discussed *ad nauseam*. For a start the OP could have got the down vote meaning right by doing some minimal research effort. For example by reading [*Voting is different on Meta*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

The question you linked to invites us to do mind-reading of voters without knowing the voters. Answers can only speculate, make a best guess. That is hardly useful for future visitors.

The question you linked to takes on a loaded subject, makes some wide, generic and bold statements. It doesn't link to any concrete examples, we just have to take the OPs word for it and then it jumps to a conclusion. Between the lines some might read yet another attack on voters. It is hardly clear what that question is really asking, what kind of answer they expect and what future visitors will gain by reading the question and its answers.

Here is some guidance for asking about voting:

- consider both up and down votes.
- don't ask about motivation of voters, anyone is free to use their vote as they see fit.
- link to prior discussions that are similar but don't address your take on the issue at hand.
- link to examples to motivate the point you want to make.
- explain how the issue affects future visitors.
- explain how the issue affects the body of knowledge any Stack Exchange site wants to be.
- make sure the premise isn't already beaten to death many times before. We don't need more duplicates.

Questions that don't address above guidance have a much higher chance to receive lots of downvotes in a short timespan. Questions that do address that guidance might gather some up votes as well, to counter some of the down votes.