# When should I ask why a question I asked was downvoted?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes, asking-questions

Once on Meta, I asked a quite badly received question and then asked why it was downvoted. My question: [Why was my question - Why does downvoting mean 'no?' - downvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389339/1370400) about why my other question: [Why does downvote sometimes seem to mean 'no'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388266/1370400) was downvoted... was downvoted. A similar scenario happened on Stack Overflow.

But on PLDI [I asked why a question was downvoted](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/426/919) and my question got upvoted.

So when is it appropriate to ask on Meta why one of my questions was downvoted?

Comment: A new community, likely full of users who don't have much experience on Stack Exchange, doing something different from other communities is not something that suggests a proper action.

Answer (score 14):

Without knowing the questions in question its hard to tell why something was downvoted.

As for PLDI - as a site in beta, talking about 'why' something was downvoted can be helpful in establishing scope and quality guidelines early on. It is a useful part of building a new site.

On most older sites those guidelines are already in place - or even answered. Our scopes are set in stone, and our quality guidelines firmly established. We have questions that cover many scenarios as well.

It got upvoted because it was useful for future users and wasn't downvoted cause it didn't show a lack of research effort.

Answer (score 9):

It seems like this question could have the title

> Why was my "why was my question downvoted" question upvoted?

It basically depends on who's online at the time, and if they perceive the question as useful or not.

A fledgling site like PLDI likely welcomes the question because it raises questions as to what is on/off-topic, i.e., a productive conversation.  Or maybe your post was perceived as an attempt at trying to refine your question-asking skills, again, a productive conversation.

A site like this (meta.SE) likely won't welcome the question.  For starters, because it's probably answered here: [I've just been downvoted. How should I react?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121350/351283), but also because of a long history of users asking "why was my question downvoted?", and when someone takes the time to write an honest answer, the OP doesn't listen, may get angry, and argues why the downvoter is wrong.  In this context, the question feels like argument-bait and is a total waste of everyone's time.  The userbase here is also seems more likely to downvote than at other sites.

The other thing is, there are many, many downvotes over the Stack Exchange network.  Many people here won't use the particular site in question.  And a lot of the time, it just doesn't matter.